# My question was closed and deleted because of its humoristic phrasing

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I've asked this question:

[What can I do with my pimped 767-300ER, which I'm no longer using](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88088/what-can-i-do-with-my-pimped-767-300er-which-im-no-longer-using)

regarding a [public dilemma in Israel today](https://www.haaretz.co.il/tmr/.premium-1.9978840) (Note: linked article is in Hebrew) in Israel today: What to do with the expensive aircraft the previous prime-minister had commissioned, and seems to be unnecessary. I phrased it as though I were that prime-minister, for dramatic/humoristic effect, but the actual question is both pertinent and on-topic for the site. Still, it was closed as supposedly off-topic and deleted as a "troll question", which is an offensive and inappropriate comment by @Jamiec.

Comment: I stand by my comment! If you were not intending to phrase it as a troll, then you would have just asked a good faith question.

Answer (score 7):

The other comments explained correctly what the issues are:

- the question is opinion-based (everyone will be able to come up with a new ridicolous way to "use" it, the non-professional tone of the question could lead to equally non-serious answers, with people trying to one-up all the previous uses) /too broad (the previous, plus, even limiting to reasonable uses, it would devolve in a list of possible uses of any aircraft, not this one specifically only, so a boring and pointless Q&A that does not add much value)
- the question appears to be politically motivated (and we don't do that here)
- the "dramatic/humoristic" effect you aimed for is in contrast to the professional tone of the site, and has thus limited the appeal of the question, instead of improving it.

Personally I don't see a way to rephrase it in such a way that it can be salvaged, and that's because the "what can be done with airplane X?" is at its core a too broad question.

Comment: 1. It's not opinion-based, since I asked for options, not what's the best thing to do; it's not too broad, because there aren't that many things you can do with an aircraft. 2. The question was not closed for these reasons. 3. The question isn't politically motivated, even if the decision is political. 4. About a "professional tone" - See [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/is-humor-allowed-in-answers). While it regards answers, I would say this applies to questions as well.

Comment: @einpoklum 1. I disagree, as you can see. I don't think discussing it further will bring us anywhere, but I'll edit to expand my point. 2. yeah, closure using the non-most-appropriate reason happens. should not, but it does. 3. but reading it seems that you are trying to use the post as a jab at the former PM,  rather than honestly discuss the issue, and the impression overcomes the intention. 4. yeah, and I am telling you that in my opinion you missed the mark, the post is not funny and does not look professional.